# If for loops doesn't yield anything, how to generate an certain output message

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

```
a = ['apple', 'banana', 'guava', 'pineapple']
x = 5

for i in range (len(a)):
    if len(a[i]) == x:
        print(a[i])
```

if the x is 5 then the output is:

```
apple
guava
```

Otherwise, if I change x to 3, then there is no output at all.
How to generate a message like "There is no elements with the expected length" if only there is no elements which meet the condition in the for loops.

So, when it goes like this

```
a = ['apple', 'banana', 'guava', 'pineapple']
    x = 3

for i in range (len(a)):
    if len(a[i]) == x:
        print(a[i])
```

Since there is no element which meet the condition inside the for loops, the expected output is:

```
There is no element with the expected lengths
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a third-party variable to keep track of what happened in the loop

```
a, x = ['apple', 'banana', 'guava', 'pineapple'], 3
at_least_one = False
for word in a:
    if len(a) == x:
        print(a)
        at_least_one = True
if not at_least_one:
    print('There is no element with the expected lengths')
```

---

Using a list-comprehension and a boolean trick

```
a, x = ['apple', 'banana', 'guava', 'pineapple'], 3
matchings = [w for w in a if len(w) == x] or ['There is no element with the expected lengths']
print("\n".join(matchings))
```

- the list `[w for w in a if len(w) == x]` gets all the correct words
- if it's empty, it's Falthy and with the `or` operator, it'll return the other operand, the text
- then print it whatever you get

Answer (score 3):

You can use an additional variable for that.

```
a = ['apple', 'banana', 'guava', 'pineapple']
x = 3
found=False
for i in range (len(a)):
    if len(a[i]) == x:
        print(a[i])
        found=True
if found==False:
    print('There is no element with the expected lengths')
```